# PTSV and calling python from C#

Tags: c#, python, visual-studio

is it possible to use python tools for visual studio in visual studio such that it allows for side by side coding of ASP.NET C# application and some python code?

Secondly how do i call a python script from C#?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

As for running python scripts in C# you can always do something like this:

```
 ProcessStartInfo start = new ProcessStartInfo();
 start.FileName = "path/to/python.exe";
 start.Arguments = string.Format("{0} {1}", cmd, args);
 start.UseShellExecute = false;
 start.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
 using(Process process = Process.Start(start))
 {
     using(StreamReader reader = process.StandardOutput)
     {
         string result = reader.ReadToEnd();
         Console.Write(result);
     }
 }
```

Passing python script as `cmd` and arguments as `args`.